# Install library with composer without updating the version of the current libraries on composer.json

Tags: php, json, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, composer-php

So today I tried to install bootstrap with the composer via composer.json. I added twbs/bootstrap in my require list at the composer.json file in my project map and runned the command

```
$ composer update
```

It was succesfully downloaded and with a few adjustments to my code and command line I can use it now in my base:html.twig file.

Unfortunately, the composer updated also my version of symfony from 2.7 to 2.8. Is there any option that I update/download bootstrap without updating my version number of Symfony, doctrine etc with the composer?
My code of composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.7@beta",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
    "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.2.*",
    "components/jquery": "1.9.*" 
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup bootstrap after downloading via composer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118367/how-to-setup-bootstrap-after-downloading-via-composer)

Comment: Not exactly, My bootstrap is up and running. My problem is that my symfony project is updated to a new version, 2.8, what I dont like.. So how can I prevent this in the future if I use the `$ composer update` command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can require the library:

```
$composer require twbs/bootstrap
```

This will put the library in a compatible version with the libraries you have.

If you also don't want to update Symfony in the future, you can add an extra version to the string:

```
"require": {
  "symfony/symfony": "~2.7.0@beta",
},
```

This will make composer understand you don't want to upgrade to 2.8 or highter versions.

Source: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#next-significant-release-operators

Comment: The "~2.7" means to install 2.7.*, 2.8.* or, if it existed, 2.9.*. However '~2.7.0' would install the latest in the 2.7 series - currently 2.7.7. The linked Composer documentation will help.

Comment: Exactly Alister, thanks for complementing my response, I've put the extra .0 but I didn't explain properly!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to install or update one dependency, you can whitelist them:

```
php composer.phar update twbs/bootstrap
```

More info in the [official doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md)

Another way is with the [require](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) command:

> The require command adds new packages to the composer.json file from
>   the current directory. If no file exists one will be created on the
>   fly.

```
php composer.phar require vendor/package:2.*
```

Hope this help