# How correctly install latest Bootstrap version into my Laravel 5.4 web application?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am pretty new in **PHP** and moreover in **Laravel** and I have the following problem: I have to correctly install latest **Bootstrap** CSS framework version into my Laravel application.

Into the **Bootstrap** download page: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download

it says that I can do it using **composer** by this statment:

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap
```

So I tryied and I obtained this output in my console:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/HotelRegistration
$ composer require twbs/bootstrap
Using version ^3.3 for twbs/bootstrap
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing twbs/bootstrap (v3.3.7) Downloading: 100%
Package illuminate/html is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laravelcollective/html instead.
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
The compiled services file has been removed.
```

What exactly means the previous output? It has been successful? My doubt is that I can't find the **bootstrap.css** file into the  **.../resources/assets** directory of my project.

Why? What am I missing? How can I use Bootstrap into my project?

**EDIT 1:** I saw that Composer have putted BootStrap in this folder:

**.../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css**

So, following this SO link: [How to setup bootstrap after downloading via composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118367/how-to-setup-bootstrap-after-downloading-via-composer)

I have tryed to do:

```
php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor/twbs/dist/css" bootstrap/css
```

to publich the content of the vendor/twbs/dist/css as an asset  but I obtain this error message:

```
Andrea@Andrea-PC MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/HotelRegistration
$ php artisan asset:publish --path="vendor/twbs/dist/css" bootstrap/css


  [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  There are no commands defined in the "asset" namespace.
```

So it seems that **asset** statment doesn't exist.

What have I to do?

Answer (score 6):

You are importing bootstrap wrong way. Mostly laravel uses composer for pulling server-side libraries. Bootstrap is used for front end basically.

Laravel By Default Provides Bootstrap for you, [see here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend).

Following are the steps which will help you.

Step 1 : Check Node.js and NPM are installed on your machine.

```
node -v
npm -v
```

If not installed don't worry here is the [link](https://nodejs.org/en/).

Step 2 : (Considering you installed node.js) Go to project root folder and execute following command.

```
npm install
```

this command will download all pre-requisites along with your bootstrap.

Step 3 : compile the required js files.

```
npm run dev
```

Step 4 : Add js file to your application.

```
<script src="/js/app.js"></script> (Or it would be already imported)
```

That's it!

You can find more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) and [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/frontend)

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Ok I have done but where are the bootstrap.css file? and how can I import it into my view? So I can use BootStrap classes...

Comment: just add `<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` to head tag. That's it!. Everything will be imported.

Comment: [Here] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) you can learn more how it works.

Answer (score 3):

If i were you i wouldn't do all of that, after a fresh installation of laravel 5.4 twitter bootstrap come out of the box you just need to load your dependancies using npm .

Install npm dependancies :

```
npm install
```

Then, Implementing Bootstrap into your project is now simple. Open resources/assets/sass/app.scss and see this line:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

now to compile all bootstrap sass files to your public folder `public/` you should use `npm run dev` or `npm run production` if you're in production environnement .

then you have all the Bootstrap styles ready for you to use. 
That’s literally all that is required.

Comment: What have I to do to run "gulp"? Have I to install it or what?

Comment: @abdou-tahir, You can't use **gulp** in Laravel 5.4, because **elixir** is replaced with **mix** in L5.4. You need to use `$ npm run (dev | production)`

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham what this statment does exactly?

Comment: Hey @blablablablablabla , i think Roham is right, i will a update my answer . you should use npm run dev to compile locally your assets and watch for changes .

Comment: In short it compiles all your js & css files and merges into single js and css file.

Comment: @AbdouTahiri so it seems to me that it compile the BootStrap .sass into the ".../public/css/app.css" file. So it means that I can import this app.css file into my view and use the Bootstrap classes? Is it or am I missing something?

Comment: @VaibhavrajRoham Is it? (previous comment). Tnx so much

Comment: Yes, its exactly !

Comment: Yes! It reduces application loading time and reduces subsequent requests.

Answer (score 1):

****Bootstrap 4 can be easily installed with following steps.****

**Step 1 — Remove existing bootstrap**

Uninstall Bootstrap

```
npm uninstall --save-dev bootstrap-sass
```

**Step 2 — Install Bootstrap 4**

Install Bootstrap 4 beta and popperjs

```
npm install --save-dev bootstrap@^4.0.0-beta.2 popper.js
```

**Step 3 — Update code references**

In resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js replace

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}
```

with

```
try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}
```

In resources/assets/sass/app.scss replace

```
@import “~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap”
```

with

@import “~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss”

```
In resources/assets/sass/_variable.scss replace

$font-size-base: 14px;
```

with

```
$font-size-base: 0.875rem;
```

**Step 4 — Recompile Assets**
Run

```
npm run dev
```

Now you have removed all Bootstrap 3 references and installed Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- run `php artisan preset bootstrap`
- install node.js if not from the [official website](https://nodejs.org/en/)

  - run `npm install`
- run `npm run dev`

---

And use these at your HTML:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```